# Not able to Load Managed Metadata Context

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, term-store, pnp-powershell, office-dev-pnp

I am trying to create Term with PowerShell in SharePoint Online to do so I have written below code but on `[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession]::GetTaxonomySession($spContext)` statement it throws an error in both of the below options,

**Option 01**

```
$User = "admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$Site = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/home"
$GroupName = "Group"
$TermSetName = "Term Set"

#Add references to SharePoint client assemblies and authenticate to Office 365 site - required for CSOM
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter your password" -AsSecureString

# Bind to MMS
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Site)
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User,$Password)
$Context.Credentials = $Creds
$MMS = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession]::GetTaxonomySession($Context)
$Context.Load($MMS)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

**Option 2**

```
$User = "admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$Site = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/home"
$GroupName = "Group"
$TermSetName = "Term Set"

#Add references to SharePoint client assemblies and authenticate to Office 365 site - required for CSOM
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter your password" -AsSecureString

$spContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Site)
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User,$Password)
$spContext.Credentials = $credentials

$web = $spContext.Web
$site = $spContext.Site
$spContext.Load($web)
$spContext.Load($site)
$spContext.ExecuteQuery()

$MMS = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession]::GetTaxonomySession($spContext)
$Context.Load($MMS)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

**Error**

> Cannot convert argument "context", with value:
>   "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext", for "GetTaxonomySession"
>   to type  "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext": "Cannot
>   convert the "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext" value of type 
>   "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext" to type
>   "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext"." At
>   C:\Ravi\TCT\WTW.TCT.3.0.6.0\TCT.SPConfiguration\TCT.SPConfiguration\Test\CreateTermTest2.ps1:38
>   char:1
>   + $MMS = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession]::GetTax ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument

I also did little research and got below article wherein both the article mentions that "SharePoint Client Component" has multiple version but for me, I do not have those components in my control panel.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/prasham/resolve-an-exception-while-retrieving-the-taxonomysession-ob/

http://prashamsabadra.blogspot.com/2016/01/office-365-sharepoint-online-exception.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the contents of your web server extension files?

I had that same error. Turns out I actually didn't have the assembly `...taxonomy.dll` file in the folder.

Once I installed the appropriate module, ensured I was referring the correct folder it worked very satisfyingly.